# Somar linhas e colunas no R

Tags: r, lista

Bom dia,

Estou utilizando o R há pouco tempo e tenho aprendido na prática. Agora me deparei com uma dificuldade com uma tabela. Como posso somar todas as linhas de determinadas colunas e exibir o resultado em uma nova coluna?

No caso minha tabela inicial tem seis colunas que serão somadas em dois blocos de três colunas. Exemplo: Contratos de Tecnologia, Programa de Computador e Desenho Industrial. Mas eu queria os resultados por países que estão separados por linhas, em uma nova coluna que vai ser Produção Tecnológica.

Um exemplo da planilha que estou trabalhando: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_HTtYC6h8ycXJO83jJiFRfWviqz-EOCHsytV0PtC2kU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Para acelerar a resposta a sua pergunta sempre use um `dput` da sua tabela no R e poste aqui o que sair no seu console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumindo que `Produção Tecnologica = CONTRATOS DE TECNOLOGIA + DESENHO NDUSTRIAL + PROGRAMA DE COMPUTADOR` e `Registros = INDICAÇÃO GEOGRÁFICA + MARCA + PATENTE`. Usando o pacote básico do R basta usar o código abaixo. O código não é bonito e nem sofisticado, mas ele é básico e de fácil entendimento. O operador `$` serve para acessar as colunas de um `data.frame` e o R automaticamente soma as linhas de suas posições correspondentes.

```
base.dados <- read.delim2("clipboard", as.is = T)

base.dados$PRODUCAOTENCOLOGIA <- base.dados$CONTRATOS.DE.TECNOLOGIA + base.dados$DESENHO.INDUSTRIAL + base.dados$PROGRAMA.DE.COMPUTADOR

base.dados$REGISTRO <- base.dados$INDICAÇÃO.GEOGRÁFICA + base.dados$MARCA + base.dados$PATENTE
```

Só para registrar usei o o comando `read.delim2`, pois dei um `ctrl+c` na base que você enviou via Google Docs.